# MS VC++ 2010 Problems compiling of added header file

Tags: visual-c++

I have added the special header file, that controls the ADLink data acquisition card.
header file: D2kDask.H
And when I compile my program, in this kind of lines of header file

```
I16 __stdcall D2K_AI_GetEvent(U16 wCardNumber, HANDLE *hEvent);
I16 __stdcall D2K_AO_GetEvent(U16 wCardNumber, HANDLE *hEvent);
```

compiler gives me this:

```
error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'HANDLE'.
```

And in these (where the type BOOLEAN exists):

```
I16 __stdcall D2K_AO_AsyncDblBufferMode (U16 CardNumber, BOOLEAN Enable);
```

this kind of errors:

```
error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'BOOLEAN'
```

I didn't change anything in header file. D2kDask.lib is added through project-properties-conf.properties-linker-input-Additional Dependencies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HANDLE is a Win32 type. You should use

```
#include <windows.h>
```

before including  D2kDask.H